# New column based on several YES/ NO columns in RStudio

Tags: r

I am fairly new to RStudio and have been able to learn and solve so many problems thanks to this and similar sites, thank you all very much!
However I have not been able to solve the following and have tried several types of searches and codes.

I have a dataset in RStudio with 1400 entries(patients) and 68 columns, no missing data.

For some of the data on medication I want to create some new columns, like "antithrombotic medication YES/NO" and "heart medication YES/NO".
These should be based on 5-10 columns that either give a YES or a NO. If any column gives a "YES", the new column should be "YES" otherwise "NO".
I have tried several versions of "mutate", "if else" etc where I also tried to use "|" to write "or" but no "luck" so far.

I have several examples, but none that I really believed in too much
.. trial and error! This one is based of a solution to a similar problem that I was able to solve

```r
hipfx_master60 <- hipfx_master60 %>%
  mutate(cardiac_HBP_antithromb_med = case_when({Diuretika="YES"|Betablokkere="YES"|Cakanalblokkere="YES"|ACEhaemmere="YES"|ATIIinhibitorer="YES"|Antithrombotica="YES"|Thrombocythammere="YES"|Vitamin_K_antagonister="YES"|Digoxin="YES"|Organiske_nitrater="YES"} ~ "YES", TRUE ~ "NO"))
```

(image removed)

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: (1) Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly. (2) You don't need `case_when` in this use, it's going to be really inefficient (row-wise calculation instead of R's preferred vectorized stuff), just use `if_else(...|...|...|..., "YES", "NO")`.

Comment: Use `==` not `=` in your conditionals, that is your problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you removed the image from your question? As an archive of questions, you have made the question much less clear by doing that. If you're worried about leaking confidential information, ***too late***, it cannot be taken back, as it is still in the history and can be rolled back by many high-reputation users on SO. (Your only hope at this point is to get a moderator or SE staff to wipe it from the history. That's not a common thing to do.) Regardless, please come back and insert some sample data to make sure the question remains "complete" enough.

Comment: Oh sorry, I must have misunderstood. I removed it because you wrote "(1) Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices." I thought that meant I should remove it. Not secret and I don't mind putting it back if that is the right thing to do.

Comment: It was just a screenshot of what the data looked like, the example of code that was there from the beginning remains unchanged

Comment: FYI, it is certainly feasible to provide more help in an answer when there is sample data to use. An image of data (as a previous comment says) is little help, mostly because I am unlikely to spend time transcribing the data into something usable. Glad the answer worked for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your data so I cannot test, but one problem is that you are using the *assignment* operator `=` instead of the *equality condition* operator `==`.

```r
hipfx_master60 <- hipfx_master60 %>%
  mutate(
    cardiac_HBP_antithromb_med = case_when(
      Diuretika == "YES" | Betablokkere == "YES" | Cakanalblokkere == "YES" |
        ACEhaemmere == "YES" | ATIIinhibitorer == "YES" | Antithrombotica == "YES" |
          Thrombocythammere == "YES" | Vitamin_K_antagonister == "YES" |
            Digoxin == "YES" | Organiske_nitrater == "YES" ~ "YES",
      TRUE ~ "NO"
    )
  )
```

In this case, `case_when` is going to be inefficient in the long run (large-ish data?). The reason is that it is doing all of its conditions row-by-row. You can vectorize it (a common R preference) with `if_else`:

```r
hipfx_master60 <- hipfx_master60 %>%
  mutate(
    cardiac_HBP_antithromb_med = if_else(
      Diuretika == "YES" | Betablokkere == "YES" | Cakanalblokkere == "YES" |
        ACEhaemmere == "YES" | ATIIinhibitorer == "YES" | Antithrombotica == "YES" |
          Thrombocythammere == "YES" | Vitamin_K_antagonister == "YES" |
          Digoxin == "YES" | Organiske_nitrater == "YES",
      "YES", "NO")
  )
```

I recommend `case_when` when you have multiple such checks and would otherwise nest `if_else` statements. After one nesting, I find the code to be difficult to see and maintain and switch to `case_when`. (The performance penalty is mostly in my head for not-large datasets. But even if slower, the readability and maintainability are often preferred.) There might be other "elegant" ways to handling multiple related conditionals without resorting to nested-nested-nested `if_else` ... as always, it depends.

Comment: Thank you so much! I used the "if_else" version, worked perfect! I love it when the internet does this instead of duckface selfies!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R approach. First reproducible data. Glancing at your data, NO seems to be much more common than YES:

```
set.seed(42)
dta <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c("YES", rep("NO", 9)), 100, replace=TRUE), 20))
```

Now compute column X6:

```
dta$X6 <- apply(dta[, c("X1", "X3", "X5")], 1, function(x) any(x=="YES"))
dta$X6 <- ifelse(dta$X6=="TRUE", "YES", "NO")
head(dta)
#    X1 X2 X3  X4  X5  X6
# 1 YES NO NO  NO YES YES
# 2  NO NO NO  NO  NO  NO
# 3 YES NO NO  NO  NO YES
# 4  NO NO NO  NO  NO  NO
# 5  NO NO NO YES  NO  NO
# 6  NO NO NO YES  NO  NO
```